# Which iOS versions support free trial?

Tags: ios-appstore

Do you know if the free trial is available on all iOS versions or maybe only on iOS > 11.2? Unfortunately, I couldn't find that information at https://developer.apple.com/app-store/subscriptions/

Comment: It shouldn't be iOS specific, but I don't have any proof for that. Also, I remember using the Apple Music trial on iOS 10.

Comment: Free trials are up to up to the individual developer. They can support them or not as suits them.